# Creation of virtual host through python

Tags: python, python-2.4

I have created a python (I m using 2.4) script to automatically create a virtual host in httpd.conf. But when I run it it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ApaPy2.py", line 2, in ?
    from io import open
ImportError: No module named io
```

This is my script

```
import os
from io import open
project = raw_input(u'Enter the name of project ')
domain = raw_input (u'Enter the domain ')
docroot = raw_input(u'Enter root folder ')

virtualhost=u"""
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin abhishek.verma@laitkor.com
    DocumentRoot /""" +docroot+ u"""/""" +project+ u"""
    ServerName """ +project+ u""".""" +domain+ u""".com
    ErrorLog logs/""" +project+ u""".com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/""" +project+ u""".com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>"""

f = open(u'/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf', u'a')
f.write(virtualhost)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `io` module was introduced in Python 2.6, so it doesn't exist in 2.4. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html):

> New in version 2.6.

The [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) keyword should work fine for what you're doing here.

Answer (score 5):

The `io` module doesn't exist in 2.4 (and you don't need it to use `open` in this case). I would also simplify your code to use string formatting using `%` instead:

```
project = raw_input(u'Enter the name of project ')
domain = raw_input (u'Enter the domain ')
docroot = raw_input(u'Enter root folder ')

virtualhost=u"""
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin abhishek.verma@laitkor.com
    DocumentRoot /%(docroot)s/%(project)s
    ServerName %(project)s.%(domain)s.com
    ErrorLog logs/%(project)s.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/%(project)s.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>"""

f = open(u'/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf', u'a')
f.write(virtualhost % dict(project=project, docroot=docroot, domain=domain)
f.close()
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Actually I have always worked on python 3 and so I was unaware of this fact. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used python 2.4, but the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html%20%22documentation) says the io module has been added in the 2.6 version, so you can't import it in 2.4.

I'd assume `open` was already a built in function in 2.4, though, so simply removing the `from io import open` line should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The io module didn't exist in Python 2.4. Your usage of open is simple, so you can omit that line and the open statement will still work correctly.